# Why is this JavaScript code with $ sign not working?

Tags: javascript

HTML file

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

Are these codes possible or not valid in JavaScript?

1.

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

2.

```
$("myid").innerHTML = "hello world";
```

Comment: try yourself in browser

Comment: try it http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yr6uq/1/

Comment: @JaykishanMehta No it shouldn't. `$("myid").innerHTML` wouldn't even work in jQuery. `$("myid")[0].innerHTML` would.

Comment: Of course, if you've already loaded jQuery or any other library which reserves '$' as a function name, you'll usually see errors when you redefine it. ;-)

Comment: @FrancisFuerte No it's not a "reserved word".

Comment: @RobRaisch you should be able to override it just fine.  If you include jQuery afterwards however, it will override your definition.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know he's trying to use (and needs to include) jQuery.

Comment: @Mash, True, if there is no currently running code which relies on `$`. If you're running Chrome, try opening your JS console and redefine `$` while on this page. *grin*

Comment: @RobRaisch works fine.  I can't even comment after I do so. :)

Comment: @Mash, well, when I redefine `$` while on this page and then attempt to do anything, even clicking on the page, my console fills up with errors. YMMV.

Comment: @RobRaisch well I'm sure there will be errors, as scripts on the page try to call $ in specific ways that it no longer can!  But you can still overwrite it.

Comment: For the record, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names if you'd like to name your JS functions like: `function ಠ_ಠ(){return true;}` ;)

Answer (score 3):

> below codes are possible or not in javascript ?

The answer to this is **yes**, that code is fine.

There is nothing wrong with your code that you've shown. As many commenters have pointed out, it works fine in a [JS fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nC2Jm/)

`$` is not, as one commenter said, a reserved word, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

---

However, I would recommend against using `$` if this code is to be used by others. `$` is often used as the shortcut to jQuery, which is what is confusing some commenters. I believe (for readability) you would be better off using a different single character.

Comment: i made a mistake. i run those codes seperatley. it works fine together in a js file

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div id="myHtml"></div>

$ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
console.log($("myHtml"));
$("myHtml").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```